# Using openoffice Calc or Excel to find variables which occur in multiple columns?

Tags: excel, duplicates, openoffice-calc

I need a way to check if a variable occurs in all of my columns at least once.

Example with 3 columns, while `Occu in Col1-3` checks if the variable which is listed in `Col3` exists in every other column. Only for `a` the formula should return "true".
How can I achieve this? I tried using "countif" but unfortunately this only works for a maximum of 2 columns.

```
+------+------+------+----------------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Occu in Col1-3 |
+------+------+------+----------------+
| a    | a    | f    |          false |
| b    | c    | a    |           true |
| c    | d    | e    |          false |
+------+------+------+----------------+
```

Any help is upvoted, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply another `COUNTIF` statement for each column:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$3,"=" & C1) * COUNTIF(B$1:B$3,"=" & C1)
```